# EF CTP5 Automatically create tables SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-ctp5

I've been using EF 4 CTP5 and was following scottgu blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Basically I would like the model to generate the table for me if it is missing.

In my case it is complaining that there is an invalid database object, that's because I don't have a table yet. I'm using SQL Server 2005, whereas the blog mentions sql express or ce.

I would like the mode to create the table, is that feature only for sql express and CE?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Basically I would like the model to generate the table for me if it is missing"

That scenario is currently not supported using CTP5 however it should be possible to do such a thing in the (near) future: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/10/22/code-first-database-evolution-aka-migrations.aspx

Currently only the following 2 initialization strategies are supported:

```
// always recreate the database 
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());
```

or

```
// recreate the database if any changes to the model are detected.
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>());
```

It should also be noted that EF creates the whole database, not just the tables, so you don't have to create the database yourself.

Comment: Thanks Steven, 

So just to clarify, if I call DbDatabase.SetInitializer say in my global.asax then it will create the databse and tables for me even with SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Excellent thanks for your help, just got confused because I think with SQL Express and CE it does it automatically without you having to initialize it like in the article. Thanks again

Comment: I think you're getting the error because you created the database yourself, if no database is found, then EF Code First creates it automatically.

Comment: the last comment was the key for me. If the database exists nothing is created. You need to drop the database(!) for new tables to be created in sql server